# Duplicate Symbols with a static library - understand the duplicate symbol error message

Tags: ios, linker

I'm integrating an external library in my iOS project. I get 11 duplicate symbols when I try to compile.

Here's an excerpt of the output:

```
duplicate symbol _serviceCallReturn in:
/Path/to/my/project/Classes/PointEngine/Device/libPointEngineSDK.a(PointEngineSDKUser.o)
/Path/to/my/project/Classes/PointEngine/Device/libPointEngineSDK.a(PointEngineSDKScanner.o)

duplicate symbol _serviceCallType in:
/Path/to/my/project/Classes/PointEngine/Device/libPointEngineSDK.a(PointEngineSDKScanner.o)
/Path/to/my/project/Classes/PointEngine/Device/libPointEngineSDK.a(PointEngineSDKProof.o)
```

What does it mean? What is the relation between, say, `PointEngineSDKUser.o` and `libPointEngineSDK.a`? Any idea what kind of misconfiguration can lead to this?

When I create an empty iOS Project and integrate the library into it, it works like a charm. The problem must be in my existing project configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In short:

- The `*.o` files are relocatable ELFs. They are products of the compiler, which always uses source files as input for doing its job.
- The `*.a` files are the ar archives. They are product of the so called [ar program](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/binutils/ar.html), which always use relocatable ELF objects as input for doing its job.

Now, to resolve the first issue from the two (*duplicate symbol _serviceCallReturn*):

1. Go to and open the PointEngineSDKUser.c and PointEngineSDKScanner.c files from which the corresponding *.o objects have been built.
2. You should find the `serviceCallReturn` variable definition in both of them, which is not correct and that's why you see the linker complaining.
3. If the original intention was to use the same variables in both .c files, then one of them should be defined using the `extern` keyword. Otherwise, use a different name for one of the variables.

Comment: Thanks! The problem is that the `libPointEngineSDK.a` are shipped as binaries. I dont have acces to the source code :/ The binaries are here: http://www.hub-to-you.net/digitalshopper.sdk/PointEngineSDK-REC.zip

Comment: I've continued to experiment, I could reproduce the error when adding CocoaPods to my test project. The Podfile only contains one pod that should be completely unrelated.

Comment: What is CocoaPods? source file or library?

Comment: I've added `NSLogger` as a pod and ran `pod install`. When opening the resulting workspace, the project won't build anymore with exactly the same duplicate symbols a the real project (which has much more pods).

Comment: As I didn't have control over the source code of the library, I've asked the editor of the library to check and update it.

Comment: I met the same problem as you。